# Is Buber's Legend of the Baal Shem Tov credible?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, agada-stories-legends, baal-shem-tov

Did [Buber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_the_Hasidim) base his stories on authentic Chassidic lore or was it his own making?

Comment: There may well be embellishments but why would he make it up?

Comment: I mean tw Wikipedia article you linked says he based it off of chassidic lore and the Besht

Comment: ["Buber's interpretation of the Hasidic tradition, however, has been criticized by Chaim Potok for its romanticization. In the introduction to Buber's Tales of the Hasidim, Potok claims that Buber overlooked Hasidism's "charlatanism, obscurantism, internecine quarrels, its heavy freight of folk superstition and pietistic excesses, its tzadik worship, its vulgarized and attenuated reading of Lurianic Kabbalah". Even more severe is the criticism that Buber de-emphasized the importance of the Jewish Law in Hasidism."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Buber)

Comment: @ezra This is simply false. In Chaim Potok’s introduction he wrote that, “some have taken Buber to task etc.” Potok himself, who grew up in a Chassidic home, does not make this statement.

Comment: That is an awesome reply.